# What would be another way to express $b=Y_n(ia)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, bessel-functions

I understand that $b=Y_n(a)$ is the Bessel Function of the second kind, and the Bessel Function of the second kind swaps between negative and positive values for $b$ repeatedly as $a$ increases, for positive values of $a$.  Also there is a modified Bessel Function of the second kind $b=K_n(a)$, in which $b$ is positive for all positive values of $a$, and decreases as $a$ increases.

I tried putting $b=Y_n(ia)$ into wolfram alpha but it did not get interpreted as the Bessel Function of the second kind with the imaginary unit.

How do I express $b=Y_n(ia)$ another way?

Comment: I think Wikipedia can answer your question, in that $I_a$ and $Y_a$ are both represented in terms of $J_a$ and $K_a$ is represented in terms of $I_a$.

Comment: Try BesselY(ia).